# How can I use different Cypress.env() variables for Circle testing?

Tags: cypress

I am doing some automatic testing on Circleci, with different enviromental variables: I need one port for my local testing and a different one for Circleci.

How can I make Cypress do that? I tried making cypress.env.circle, but that does not seem to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [cypress docs explain 5 ways to set variables](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables.html#Setting).

To use one port locally and one on CircleCI I would:

1. Add a default port to `cypress.json` under the `env` section for local use so you don't have to think about it, and anyone else contributing will have a working version.
2. Set an environment variable in CircleCI named `cypress_VAR_NAME` which will override default in cypress.json

cypress.json example

```
{   
    "env": {
        "the_port": 5000
      }
}
```

CircleCI variable would then be `cypress_the_port` and you would read it in your specs as `parseInt(Cypress.env('the_port'))` (assuming your spec needs an integer for port)